# Openni kinect error make

Tags: openni-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!! I'm trying to install the drivers's openni kinect in Ubuntu with ROS electric.

I installed ROS following "the ROS installation instrucion" and I did the first 9 tutorials, but when i tried to install the openni kinect following http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect , the comand "make" fail.

That's the error message in the terminal:

```
miles@nono:~/drivers$ make
cd openni && make
make[1]: se ingresa al directorio «/home/miles/drivers/openni»
git clone https://github.com/OpenNI/OpenNI.git build/openni
make[1]: git: No se encontró el programa
make[1]: *** [build/openni] Error 127
make[1]: se sale del directorio «/home/miles/drivers/openni»
make: *** [openni_lib] Error 2
```

Please....help me :(

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11295/openni-kinect-error-make/) by [Rikki](https://answers.ros.org/users/1114/rikki/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2011-09-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rikki](https://answers.ros.org/users/1114/rikki/) on 2011-09-23**:
I have installed  ros-electric-desktop-full. And for openin kinect,  I only installed ros-electric-openni-kinect and rosinstall.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-09-23**:
Please provide more information on what you have installed and how you did so, otherwise it's very hard to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm pretty sure that the error you're experiencing is because you do not have "git" installed.

If you're on ubuntu:

sudo apt-get install git

---

Originally posted by [John Hoare](https://answers.ros.org/users/159/john-hoare/) with karma: 765 on 2011-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are using electric on Ubuntu I suggest that you use the debian based installation, listed at the top of the linked page, which is already compiled.  If you're already using that you don't need to compile.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-09-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-09-26**:
yes, the packages which come from apt have already had "make" called on them.  calling "make" compiles the source code into binary machine code which can be executed.  The error you're getting is just the first of many as the packages are also read only too.

**Comment by [Rikki](https://answers.ros.org/users/1114/rikki/) on 2011-09-23**:
but... you say i don´t need to complie? I don´t need to do "make"?

**Comment by [Rikki](https://answers.ros.org/users/1114/rikki/) on 2011-09-23**:
If I do the steps to "debian user" does not work either -> "$ make debian" produces the same error